# Passing constructor args for Spring CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an application that uses a class `myClass` that implements Spring `CommanLineRunner`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ . . . } )

public class myClass implements CommandLineRunner {
       . . .
    public myClass() { . . . }

    public myClass( String anArg ) { . . . }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication( myClass.class );
            application.setWebEnvironment( false );
            application.run( args );
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
           . . .
    } 
}
```

`this` in the `run` method is bound to an instance of `myClass` that Spring constructs automagically.  My problem is that for this constructing, I want to use the non-default constructor that takes an argument
and I want to pass to that argument one of the command line `args`.

How do I tell Spring to use the non-default constructor, and how do I supply a value to the constructor argument `anArg`?

Comment: I would split `myClass` into a separate class and in your `run()` method call the constructor that you want.

Comment: ``anArg`` would be a class field which constructor would set (may be after some processing). So essentially, you can set the field or change object state even after instance has been created using default constructor --- from inside run method.

Comment: @nickb Doesn't `myClass` require a `run` method in order to implement `CommandLineRunner`?

Comment: @lokesh I think you are saying I could define `myclass.initialize( String anArg )` that I call from the `run` method.  True, but since "myClass" really isn't functional until it's initialized, I'd prefer to use the constructor to do that.

Comment: @MarkLavin, Yeh! Make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to pass other instances to `CommandLineRunner` it is recommended to separate your application class from the `CommandLineRunner` interface. So, your main class would look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
}
```

In the other hand we should instanciate the `CommandLineRunner` as a component:

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private MyOtherComponent otherComponent

    @Autowired
    public MyCommandLineRunner(MyOtherComponent otherComponent) {
        this.otherComponent = otherComponent;
    }

    public void run(String... args) {
         otherComponent.setArg(arg[0]);
    }
}
```

A more convenient way is to create a bean by passing a lambda function to it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initialize(MyOtherComponent otherComponent) {

        return args -> {
            otherComponent.setArg(arg[0]);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ervin, I really don't understand how the code above manages to convey the command line `args[]` to some constructor for a helper class.  Could you please take a look again at my setup, above?

Comment: You can take any argument you want and pass it to another component which is injected. Since the component wes created previously by Spring, you can not pass the argument to the constructor, you have to use setter: `otherComponent.setArg(args[0])`.

Comment: If you don't want your other class to be managed by Spring, you can create it inside the `run` method and call there whichever constructor you want..

Comment: Ervin, about "If you don't want...":   My actual class itself contains an @Autowire, so it's my impression that instances of my class have to be created by Spring, not by calling a constructor with an argument.  Am  I correct about this requirement?

Comment: Yes, Spring has to create your object in order to be able to inject the instance which is autowired.